# Hybris Solr - how to exclude certain facet values when creating SearchQueryData

Tags: solr, facet, sap-commerce-cloud

I am searching in Hybris using Solr. There are certain facet values for category that I want to exclude from that specific(those categories need to be visible to other searches) search. My Solr query is as following:

```
q=*:*&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.dictionary=en&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.q=&fq={!tag=fk6}(type\-facet_string:ANSI)&fq=(((catalogId:"ProductCatalog") AND (catalogVersion:Online)))&start=0&rows=100&facet=true&facet.field=allCategories_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk0}productLine_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk8}style-facet_string&facet.field={!ex=fk5}price_usd_string&facet.field={!ex=fk4}allPromotions_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk6}type-facet_string&facet.field={!ex=fk1}size-facet_string&facet.field=categoryPath_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk9}availableInStores_string_mv&facet.field=category_string_mv&sort=name_sortable_en_sortabletext asc,score desc&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=-1&facet.sort=count
```

I don't have the ability to use raw query. All I can use is Hybris native SearchStateData and SearchQueryData. Category facet can be included in the search but I need to exclude from it i.e CategoryA and CategoryB. Right now my code just sets the value in SearchQueryData as a String in a following way:

```
":type-facet:" + type; or ":category:" + category
```

I have tried `:category:(-\"CategoryA\")`; but it does not end up in the final Solr query. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In the backoffice of hybris you can install the **Commerce Search Perspective** with the extension **backofficesolrsearch**.

In this perspecetive you can enable or disable facets for searching in frontend. Is this what you are looking for?

[Here](https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/6731f3be73be4e6782bbf546bac86742.html) is the belongig hybris wiki page to it.

Comment: I can't disable the values globally. It needs to be done for this search only.

Answer (score 0):

Refer `SearchResponseFacetsPopulator` and you can override its method by creating custom populator

`MySearchResponseFacetsPopulator` :

```
public class MySearchResponseFacetsPopulator<FACET_SEARCH_CONFIG_TYPE, INDEXED_TYPE_TYPE, INDEXED_PROPERTY_TYPE, INDEXED_TYPE_SORT_TYPE, ITEM>
        extends
        SearchResponseFacetsPopulator<FACET_SEARCH_CONFIG_TYPE, INDEXED_TYPE_TYPE, INDEXED_PROPERTY_TYPE, INDEXED_TYPE_SORT_TYPE, ITEM>
{

    @Override
    public void populate(
            final SolrSearchResponse<FACET_SEARCH_CONFIG_TYPE, INDEXED_TYPE_TYPE, INDEXED_PROPERTY_TYPE, SearchQuery, INDEXED_TYPE_SORT_TYPE, SearchResult> source,
            final FacetSearchPageData<SolrSearchQueryData, ITEM> target)
    {
        super.populate(source, target);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<FacetData<SolrSearchQueryData>> buildFacets(final SearchResult solrSearchResult,
            final SolrSearchQueryData searchQueryData, final IndexedType indexedType)
    {
       // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

xml :

```
<alias name="defaultMyCommerceSearchResponseFacetsPopulator" alias="commerceSearchResponseFacetsPopulator" />
        <bean id="defaultMyCommerceSearchResponseFacetsPopulator"   class="com.my.facades.populators.MySearchResponseFacetsPopulator"
            parent="defaultCommerceSearchResponseFacetsPopulator" />
```